# rake system command causes bundle error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, rake-task

I'm trying to run this rake task but it keeps on returning the following error:

```
Could not find libv8-3.3.10.4 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

When I try and run `bundle install` bundler says everything is up to date.

I am running the task using this command:
`bundle exec rake deploy:staging`

Here's what my rake task looks like:

```
  task :staging  do
    app = "heroku-app-name"

    puts "Turn maintenance on"
    system "heroku maintenance:on --app #{app}"
  end
```

Comment: From what I've read, there are different instances of libv8 for different platforms and that's caused this kind of error before. Does `gem list` show any more detail about libv8 besides the version number? e.g., `x86_64` or whatever?

Comment: Could try - `gem install --version '=3.3.10.4' libv8`

Comment: is that error coming from heroku or only on your local machine?

Comment: @phoet This error is coming from my local machine. Each of these commands runs find in the console, it's only when I attempt to put them in a rake task that I then get these errors

Comment: @mbratch @David I'm currently using `libv8 (3.3.10.4 x86_64-darwin-12)`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to shell out to heroku commands from a rake task by wrapping the command in a Bundler.with_clean_env block like as follows:

```
Bundler.with_clean_env do
  system "heroku maintenance:on --app #{app}"
end
```